# Bootstrap 4 carousel in Angular project

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is what's in my component's html

```
<div id="arrowslider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://img.webnots.com/2017/05/BS_Slide1.jpg" alt="Slide1">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://img.webnots.com/2017/05/BS_Slide2.jpg" alt="Slide2">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://img.webnots.com/2017/05/BS_Slide3.jpg" alt="Slide3">
    </div>
</div>
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#arrowslider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous Slide</span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#arrowslider" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next Slide</span>
</a>
```

The carousel displays initially image, but it only shows the initial and the navigation goes to http://localhost:4200/#arrowslider

Is this an issue with the alpha version of the bootstrap package?

Comment: check your browser console yet?

Comment: Create a live example on https://plnkr.co